# _.findWhere from underscorejs to JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I am trying to implement this code: http://jsfiddle.net/wQysh/351/ in my project.

Everything is fine except for the line:

```
t = _.findWhere(sc, { id : Number(a.trim()) });
```

They have used underscorejs and I want to translate this to JQuery without using another lib.

I went through the doc and it stated:

> findWhere_.findWhere(list, properties)
>
> Looks through the list and returns the first value that matches all of the key-value pairs listed in properties.
>
> If no match is found, or if list is empty, undefined will be returned.

But still I am confused about this since I am not sure what to return exactly (as first value). Can anyone give me a JQuery alternative to that line?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: There is no jQuery alternative, you can implement findWhere in plain ol' javascript.

Comment: even javascript would do.. but how do I?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck in your attempt?

Comment: i just dont know how to work on the fiddle given without underscorejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't the generic nature of `_.findWhere()` you can use a simple `while` loop, and compare the id to the numeric value of a ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wQysh/591/)):

```
t = 0; // t is used as a counter
aValue = Number(a.trim()); // assign the value to a variable instead of iterating it
while (t < sc.length && sc[t].id !== aValue) { t++; }; // find the index where the id is the as the aValue

t < sc.length && toSet.push(sc[t]); // if t is less the sc.length we found the item in the array
```

If you need a `findWhere` without underscore try this [gist](https://gist.github.com/aaronmccall/9751450).

Answer (score 0):

I also used this example in my project. And also needed use JQuery instead of Underscore.

Here is my solution:

```
t = sc.filter(function (el) { return el.id === a });
```

It work perfect for me;

If you use number for ids, you can also convert a to integer

```
t = sc.filter(function (el) { return el.id === parseInt(a, 10) });
```